# Separate all character of a string by FS (awk)

Tags: awk, printf

I though it would have been a simple task but nope !

input (pipe separated):

```
record1|ABCDEFGH
record2|IJKLMNOP
```

I would need this output:

```
record1|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H
record2|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P
```

What I tried so far:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{a = split($2, b, ""); for(i=1; i<=a; i++){printf("%s|%s, $1, b[i](i==a? "\n":"|"))}}' input
```

and I get:

```
record1|A
record1|B
record1|C
...
```

I don't get it! If someone could explain it to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `printf`s are all over the shop. With modifications as shown below, it works as expected

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{a = split($2, b, "");
   printf "%s|", $1; 
   for(i=1; i<=a; i++){printf("%s%s", b[i],i==a? "\n":"|")}}' input
```

Comment: Thanks 1_CR! I had no idea we could split `printf` for each field. It is much more flexible than I though actually.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way using `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' '{ gsub(/./, FS "&", $2) }1' OFS= file
```

Results:

```
record1|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H
record2|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! This one is way easier, really didn't think about substitutions.

Comment: +1 I'd say this is the best solution. For readability, probably we can move OFS inside and use print instead of 1. awk -F "|" 'BEGIN {OFS=//} {gsub(/./, FS "&", $2);print}' input

Comment: @user3088572: Thanks, but I disagree that that improves readability. If you wanted to use a `BEGIN` block, it would be better to also define your `FS` in there too, rather than using it in conjunction with the `-F` flag. And `OFS=//` is better written as `OFS=""`. It's also much more awkish/perly to simply return true than it is to use a `print` statement.

Answer (score 2):

In this code you won't need `OFS` and `IFS` is defined using `-F` switch.

```
awk -F "|" '{split($2,b,"");printf("%s",$1);for(i=1;i<=length($2);i++) printf("|%c",b[i]);printf("\n")}' input
```

Or if you prefer not to use an extra variable b and split in favor of using substr(), the code can be written as.

```
awk -F "|" '{printf("%s",$1);for(i=1;i<=length($2);i++) printf("|%c",substr($2,i,1));printf("\n")}' input
```

Comment: I think you mean `FS`. `IFS` is a bash-ism.

Comment: @Steve - yes you are right. I meant FS but wrote IFS. I don't need to update my reply as you already provided the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

By sed

```
sed ':a;s/|.\B/&|/;ta' file
```